# Adding new columns to created dataframe from merging csv files

Tags: r, dataframe, read.csv

Hope someone can help me with this problem. Basically, I have several csv files and I want to merge all of them to create a single dataframe. Each csv file has multiple rows (main part of the csv file), then there are some empty rows and then some information about the specific file. For example, csv file 1:

```
a b c d 
1 2 4 3
4 3 4 2


p 2
t 3
```

csv file 2:

```
a b c d 
0 2 1 8
3 4 1 2


p 4
t 6
```

I have been able to join the main part of all the csv files. For this, I just created a function. In this particular example, I just need the three first rows, so:

```
multmerge=function(mypath) {
  filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
  datalist= lapply(filenames, function (x) read.csv(file=x, header=TRUE, 
  nrows=3))
  Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, all = TRUE), datalist)}

  full_data <- multmerge(mypath)
```

And the result is something like this:

```
a b c d 
1 2 4 3
4 3 4 2
0 2 1 8
3 4 1 2
```

However, I would like the dataframe full_data to include the variables from the information part of each csv file, so at the end I would have something like this:

```
a b c d p t
1 2 4 3 2 3
4 3 4 2 2 3
0 2 1 8 4 6
3 4 1 2 4 6
```

Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your logic to separate main data from information about the specific file.ex   a b c d and p t

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `data.table` solution.

To stay dynamic, it read each file a couple of times.. This might slow things down considerably when working with large files (or a very large amount of files).
But this is, as far as I know, only way to skip the bottom part of a file using `data.table::fread()`.
Added bonus of this solution is that your file can have *any number of lines*. The code only strips the final four (two blank, and the lines with the p/t-values).

My sample data exist of two files, `./csv1.csv` and `./csv2.csv`, containing your sample data from the question.

What happens in de code below:
- Build a list of files you want to read
- Read the files using `data.table::fread()` within a custom function that:
_ - determines the number of lines in the file to read;
_ - first reads all but the last four lines of each file;
_ - then reads the last two lines of each file;
_ - combines these two results in the format we want.
- Bind the list together to one data.table

```
#get a list of files you want to read
filelist <- list.files( path = "./", pattern = "^csv[12]\\.csv", full.names = TRUE )

#read the files to a list, using a custom function
l <- lapply( filelist, function(x) {
  #get the length of the file first, by reading in the file 
  # sep = "" is for faster reading of the file
  length_file <- nrow( fread(x, sep = "", header = TRUE ) )
  #use data.table::fread to read in the file EXCEPT the four last lines
  file_content <- data.table::fread( x, nrows = length_file - 4 , fill = TRUE )
  #use data.table::fread to read in the file ONLY the last two lines
  file_tail    <- data.table::fread( x, skip = length_file - 2 , fill = TRUE )
  #build final output
  output <- file_content[, `:=`( p = file_tail[ V1 == "p", V2 ],
                                 t = file_tail[ V1 == "t", V2 ] )]
})

# [[1]]
#    a b c d p t
# 1: 1 2 4 3 2 3
# 2: 4 3 4 2 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
#    a b c d p t
# 1: 0 2 1 8 4 6
# 2: 3 4 1 2 4 6

#use data.table::rbindlist() to bind the list to a single data.table
data.table::rbindlist( l )

#    a b c d p t
# 1: 1 2 4 3 2 3
# 2: 4 3 4 2 2 3
# 3: 0 2 1 8 4 6
# 4: 3 4 1 2 4 6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I have to say that the information part actually has more than two variables. I have followed your suggestion. However, I obtain the following error:  Error in `[.data.table`(file_content, , `:=`(participant = file_tail[V1 ==  : 
  In `:=`(col1=val1, col2=val2, ...) form, all arguments must be named.

Comment: hard to say without sample... you could define x by hand (using `x = filelist[1]`) and then look what `length_file`, `file_content` and `file_tail` look like... are they what you would expect? If so, then take a look at how `output` is being built.